# FF extension: need some help observing POSTs

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, observer-pattern, channel

I'm trying to write an extension that observes HTTP requests, and specifically POSTs.  I'm having trouble accessing *all* of them - some things are slipping through, and I don't know why.  I assume it's due to other tabs, iframes or XHR requests.  What I'd like to do is create a single listener/handler, and funnel all the requests through it.  Can someone assist?  For example:

```
myObj = function(){}
myObj.prototype = {
  observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
    if (aTopic == "http-on-modify-request") {
      aSubject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
      // aSubject is now looking at the request, call method
    }
  }
}

var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
      .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);

observerService.addObserver(myObj, "http-on-modify-request",   false);
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code. Check the error console and see if there's any good information there.